# Uniform continuity of continuous real-valued function from space of trace-class operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\phi$ be a function from the space of trace-class operators on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ into the reals. Assume that $\phi$ is continuous and consider the restriction of $\phi$ to an open ball of radius $M$. Is this restriction uniformly continuous? I know of the Heine-Cantor theorem but since the ball is not compact, I'm not sure it is useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space without isolated points. If every continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous then $X$ is necessarily compact.

This shows that the answer to you question is NO. (take $X$ be the open unit ball of $\mathcal H$).

Proof of above theorem: Suppose $X$ is not compact. Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence with no convergent
subsequence. There exists a sequence $\{y_{n}\}$ such that $0<d(x_{n},y_{n})<%
\frac{1}{n}$. The set $\{x_{n}:n\geq 1\}\cup \{y_{n}:n\geq 1\}$ has no limit
points. Define $f(x_{n})=n,f(y_{n})=2n,n=1,2,...$. Extend $f$ to a
continuous function on $X$. The extended function is obviuosly not uniformly
continuous.

Comment: I'm not asking that it is uniformly continuous, only on the restriction to an open ball of radius $M$.

Comment: My $X$ is the open unit ball, not the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.  @Lundborg